# Theme broken after update to magento 2.2.2

Tags: theme, upgrade, magento2.2.2

Update from Magento 2.1.9 to 2.2.2 has caused my custom theme to break and I have no idea how to get this working again. It seems to be loading luma theme with my custom blocks loading in?

I have tried to di compile and re-deploy static content and setup upgrade but still no luck.

Any ideas on why my theme doesn't work?

**Screenshot:**
https://ibb.co/kwgxx6

Thanks

Comment: please show your error to check more in details

Comment: Please check log files

Comment: I've added a screenshot. I have no idea what is happening. Theme works fine with magento 2.1.9